# Bootstrap modal stack with google map

Tags: google-maps

I am having problems displaying a google map in a Bootstrap modal. See below

[image: you can see in this pict]

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whats wrong with that, but i try to solve your problem.
This is for replacing the modal, may you can use this code to replace map again.

```
 $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
    modal_this = this
    $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
        if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length
        // add whatever conditions you need here:
        &&
        !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
            modal_this.$element.focus()
        }
    });
};
```